# Categorical description of Alexander horned sphere?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

Looking at the construction of the Alexander horned sphere:

1. Is it possible to describe as some kind
   of direct limit of spaces?
2. How can one formally see this?

Comment: In what category?

Comment: Well I guess I'd expect it to just be in $\mathsf{Top}$

Comment: Any non-empty topological space can be described as a direct limit in lots of ways. How do you want the description to help with understanding the Alexander horned sphere?

Comment: @Exterior ? The horned sphere is topologically the standard sphere, that's the point I think, It's about how it's embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, so I don't think you can't talk about it as just an object in $\text{Top}$.

Comment: Right. In that case maybe some kind of limit involving the homotopy groups of the complements of the horn "iterations"?